VBA Excel inpuit box in the form VBA alerts can't be disabled
I would like to disable the VBA alert informing, that "the data is already here".

I tried the following solutions:
Disabling VBA alerts
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkQcYl3Gquc
https://www.excelmadeeasy.com/excel-vba-turn-off-alerts.php
which led me to the following approach:
Private Sub DocumentIDTextBox1_Change()
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Range("AA22").Value = " Document: "
Range("AA22").Font.Bold = True
Range("AB22").Value = DocumentIDTextBox1.Value
Range("AB22").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AC22"), DataType:=xlDelimited, 
Other:=True, OtherChar:="-"
End Sub

but the alert keeps appearing.
Is there any way of turn it off?

I am afraid that you cannot suppress this warning (this is not an Input Box...), since there are values in the cells where TextToColumns tries to return. Excel warns about this aspect and requires your acceptance to overwrite.
But you can clear the calculated necessary cells content before using TextToColumns...
Please, try the next adapted code:
Sub supressWarning()
 Dim cellRng As Range: Set cellRng = Range("AA22")
 
 With cellRng
    .value = " Document: "
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Offset(, 1).value = DocumentIDTextBox1.Value 'text separated by "-"
    .Offset(, 2).Resize(, UBound(Split(.Offset(, 1).value, "-")) + 1).Clear
    .Offset(, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(, 2), DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="-"
 End With
End Sub

This solves the actual issue, but it will not bother you if the respective text box value is written programmatically, at once. Otherwise, it may be annoying to run the event code after each character you add to the text box value/text.
In such a case, maybe AfterUpdate event should be more suitable, I think...
